# Are there Christians who believe that Jesus does not have a physical body right now?

Tags: christology, denomination-survey, resurrection-of-jesus, ascension, body-of-christ

I've researched about this topic online and I could only find one Christian website so far that affirms this belief.

https://www.bible.ca/d-Jesus-body-now.htm

Does anybody else know if a particular Christian denomination believes this way too? Personally, it makes sense, logically, that Jesus doesn't have a physical body because human bodies freeze in space without a suit. Colossians 1:15 also explicitly states that the Son is the image of the **invisible** God.

Comment: Did you happen to read, Luke 24:36-9 ...touch me and see, for a spirit does not have flesh and bones as you see that I have.’

Comment: Yes but that was before His ascension into Heaven, where, according to Christian dogma, He currently lives. Anyways, I'm asking to see if there's any Christians who actually believes that He **currently** does not have a physical body.

Comment: Do you want to include the Christians who believe he was only ever spiritually resurrected, or do you want to restrict it to those who believe he did have a complete physical/bodily resurrection?

Answer (score 3):

**Jehovah’s Witnesses** believe that the body of Jesus was disposed of by Jehovah God, dissolved into its constituent elements or atoms, and what came out of the tomb was a spirit creature.

> **JESUS’ FLESHLEY BODY DISSOLVED:** What happened to the perfect fleshly body of Jesus after his death?  Was it preserved so that in time men will look upon it in worship? or does Jesus still have this fleshly body in the heavens, “spiritualized” so that it can be seen and worshiped? Neither. The Scriptures answer: It was disposed of by Jehovah God, dissolved into its constituent elements or atoms...  Moses’ body returned to the dust by process of decay, as all human bodies do, but not so in Jesus’ case, for it is written: “For thou wilt not leave my soul to Sheol; neither wilt thou suffer thy holy one to see corruption.” (Ps. 16:10, AS; Acts 2:31) So God caused Jesus’ body to disappear, but not corrupt, meaning that it was dissolved, disintegrated back into the elements from which all human bodies are made.—John 20:1-13.
>
> **JESUS RESURRECTED WITH SPIRIT ORGANISM:**  The resurrected Jesus was given a spirit body: “He being put to death in the flesh, but being made alive in the spirit.” (1 Pet. 3:18, NW)

The article goes on say that the bodies that Jesus appeared in after his resurrection were materialized bodies.  The article concludes that those who refuse to recognize the signs of Jesus’ invisible presence because of looking for his coming in a body of flesh are mistaken.  Source: *Watchtower 1 September 1953 pp. 517-520 article The Fleshly Body of Jesus* https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1953641?q=resurrection+jesus+body&p=par

> Hence Jehovah God the Father, who has life-giving power in himself, raised his Son from the dead on the third day to immortal life in heaven, in the spirit realm. ... When Jesus ascended to heaven forty days after his resurrection from the dead, he did not take the sacrificed human body to heaven with him—an impossibility!—but took with him the value of his sacrificed perfect human life, in order to present this to the heavenly Father in behalf of mankind.  Source: Watchtower 1 December 1964 pp.717-726  https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1964883?q=resurrection+spirit&p=par

Here is a quotation from a more recent Watchtower article:

> The apostles knew that Jesus’ resurrection was different from the resurrections that preceded it. People who were brought back to life earlier came back with physical bodies and eventually died again. Jesus was resurrected with a spirit body that was imperishable. (Read Acts 13:34.) Peter wrote that Jesus “was put to death in the flesh but made alive in the spirit.” Moreover, “he is at God’s right hand, for he went to heaven, and angels and authorities and powers were made subject to him.” (1 Pet. 3:18-22) The previous resurrections were both marvelous and miraculous, but none compared to this supreme miracle.  Source: *The Resurrection of Jesus—Its Meaning for Us – Watchtower 15 November 2014 pp. 3-7*  https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2014842?q=resurrection+spirit&p=par

With regard to the return of Christ Jesus, Jehovah’s Witnesses believe he will be invisible:

> In what form does Christ return? He was resurrected as an invisible spirit person. (1 Peter 3:18) Then, he went to heaven and sat at God’s right hand. (Psalm 110:1) Much later, Jesus was brought before Jehovah God, “the Ancient of Days,” who granted Jesus power to rule over mankind. So Jesus returns, not as a human, but as an invisible King.  Source: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2013888?q=return+Jesus&p=par

Jehovah’s Witnesses believe that after Jesus resurrection he materialised before his disciples to look like a human (even eating and drinking with them), but when he ascended into heaven, he was a spirit.  Therefore they say Jesus does not have a physical body right now.  Furthermore, when Jesus returns, they say it will not be in bodily form, but he will be an invisible spirit.

Please be aware that I am merely presenting the official view of Jehovah’s Witnesses.

Comment: (Up-voted +1 for a very clear presentation.) This misrepresents Jesus of Nazareth as a kind of charlatan to say to his disciples _Behold my hands and my feet, that it is I myself: handle me, and see; for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me have._ . . .  when, in fact, it was not (they say) his real and true status, but just a misrepresentation of his real condition.

Comment: @NigelJ The Greek word for spirit, *pneu'ma*, can refer to a spirit person as well as to an apparition or a vision. Jesus was showing them that he was real, and not just an illusion or figment of their imagination. On the other hand, in 1 Peter 3:18, Jesus is said to have been resurrected as a spirit person.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. Very interesting. Personally, I believe that Jesus rose physically but when He ascended into Heaven, He shed His physical body and is now a spirit. Is this a unique view or...?

Comment: @4castle The New World Translation at 1 Peter 3:18 says Jesus was “made alive IN the spirit” but the KJAV says Jesus was “quickened BY the Spirit”. The NIV says Jesus was “made alive BY the Spirit”. The NLT and ESV say “he was raised to life in the Spirit” but that is not the same thing as saying he was resurrected AS a spirit. I mention this simply to point out the uniqueness of the Jehovah’s Witness take on the resurrection of Jesus. I am not about to argue against that view because this question is not for debate. It is up to you to post an answer if you want to explain the official view.

Comment: @AngelusVastator  I don’t know if your view is unique. There may be some denominations that think Jesus shed his physical body when he ascended into heaven – perhaps Pentecostals?  I don’t know. Then there is the view of Latter Day Saints, but I have no desire to go there.

Comment: @AngelusVastator I want to touch on you saying what you personally believe: "He shed His physical body and is now a spirit." Can you please reconcile the following verses in opposition to what you personally believe. Acts 1:11, 1 Corinthians 15:38, 15:43, 15:53, Philippians 3:21, 1 John 3:2 and Revelation 21:4.   I purposefully just gave you the references so you could read the verses for yourself in context. Christians will have a "spiritual body" like Jesus but it will not be "pure" spirit. God only has to speak once for it to be the truth. It is our understanding that is usually in error.

Comment: The spiritual body can refer to soul, although there's nothing that can prevent it from having a physical appearance, like how God in the OT physically appeared many times despite being spirit. And for the last verse, that is where the spiritual body truly receives its new physical body. As you read it in context, you'll realise that God is operating this new universe with new physical laws.